# want to expand a large bipartite network plot avoid vertices overlapped

Tags: r, igraph

I was plotting a bipartite graph using igraph package with R. There are about 10,000 edges, I want to expand the width of the whole plot to avoid state vertices overlapped.

my data looks like this:

```
> test2 
                 user_id state  meanlat    meanlon countUS countS degState
                   <chr> <chr>    <dbl>      <dbl>   <int>  <int>    <int>
1 -_1ctLaz3jhPYc12hKXsEQ    NC 35.19401  -80.83235     909      3    18487
2 -_1ctLaz3jhPYc12hKXsEQ    NV 36.11559 -115.18042      29      3    37884
3 -_1ctLaz3jhPYc12hKXsEQ    SC 35.05108  -80.96166       4      3      665
4 -0wUMy3vgInUD4S6KJInnw    IL 40.11227  -88.22955       2      3     1478
5 -0wUMy3vgInUD4S6KJInnw    NV 36.11559 -115.18042      23      3    37884
6 -0wUMy3vgInUD4S6KJInnw    WI 43.08051  -89.39835      20      3     3963
```

and below is my code on graph creating and setting.

```
g2 <- graph_from_data_frame(test2,directed = F)
V(g2)$type <- ifelse(names(V(g2)) %in% UserStateR$user_id, 'user', 'state')
V(g2)$label <- ifelse(V(g2)$type == 'user', " ", paste(names(V(g2)),"\n",as.character(test2$degState),sep=""))
V(g2)$size <- ifelse(V(g2)$type == 'user', 3, 20)
V(g2)$color <- ifelse(V(g2)$type == 'user', 'wheat', 'salmon')
V(g2)$type <- ifelse(names(V(g2)) %in% UserStateR$user_id, T, F )
E(g2)$color <- heat.colors(8)[test2$countS]
plot(g2,layout=layout.bipartite(g2, types = names(V(g2)) %in% UserStateR$state, hgap = 50, vgap = 50))
```

as you can see, I have tried to change the `hgap` and `vgap` arguments, but it doesn't work apparently. I have also tried `asp` argument, but that is not what I want.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this might be too late for @floatsd but I was struggling with this today and had a really hard time finding an answer, so this might help others out.

First, in general, there is a an attribute to `iplot.graph` called `asp` that very simply controls how rectangular your plot is. Simply do

```
l=layout.bipartite(CCM_net)    
plot(CCM_net, layout=l, asp=0.65)
```

for a wide plot. `asp` smaller than 1 gives you a wide plot, `asp` larger than 1 a tall plot.

However, this might still not give you the layout you want. The bipartite command basically generates a matrix with coordinates for your vertices, and I actually don't understand yet how it comes up with the x-coordinates, so I ended up changing them myself.
Below the example (I am assuming you know how to turn your data into data frames with the edge list and edge/vertex attributes for making graphs so am skipping that).
My data is `CCM_data_sign` and is

```
    from   to value
2    EVI MAXT  0.67
4    EVI MINT  0.81
5    EVI    P  0.70
7    EVI   SM  0.79
8    EVI  AMO  0.86
11  MAXT  EVI  0.81
18  MAXT  AMO  0.84
21 MEANT  EVI  0.88
28 MEANT  AMO  0.83
29 MEANT  PDO  0.71
31  MINT  EVI  0.96
39  MINT  PDO  0.78
40  MINT  MEI  0.66
41     P  EVI  0.91
49     P  PDO  0.77
50     P  MEI  0.71
51   PET  EVI  0.90
58   PET  AMO  0.89
59   PET  PDO  0.70
61    SM  EVI  0.94
68    SM  AMO  0.90
69    SM  PDO  0.81
70    SM  MEI  0.73
74   AMO MINT  0.93
76   AMO  PET  0.66
79   AMO  PDO  0.71
80   AMO  MEI  0.83
90   PDO  MEI  0.82
```

The data frame I generated for graphing is called `CCM_net`.
First a bipartite plot without any layout adjustments

```
V(CCM_net)$size<-30
l=layout.bipartite(CCM_net)
plot(CCM_net,
     layout=l,
     edge.arrow.size=1,
     edge.arrow.width=2,
     vertex.label.family="Helvetica",
     vertex.label.color="black",
     vertex.label.cex=2,
     vertex.label.dist=c(3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3),
     vertex.label.degree=c(pi/2,-pi/2,-pi/2,-pi/2,-pi/2,-pi/2,-pi/2,-pi/2,pi/2,pi/2,pi/2), #0 is right, “pi” is left, “pi/2” is below, and “-pi/2” is above
     edge.lty=1)
```

This gives you the following
[image: regualt_bipartite]

If I use `asp` I get the following

```
plot(CCM_net,
     layout=l,
     edge.arrow.size=1,
     vertex.label.family="Helvetica",
     vertex.label.color="black",
     vertex.label.cex=2,
     vertex.label.dist=c(3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3),
     vertex.label.degree=c(pi/2,-pi/2,-pi/2,-pi/2,-pi/2,-pi/2,-pi/2,-pi/2,pi/2,pi/2,pi/2), #0 is right, “pi” is left, “pi/2” is below, and “-pi/2” is above
     edge.arrow.width=2,
     edge.lty=1,
     asp=0.6) # controls how rectangular the plot is. <1 = wide, >1 = tall
dev.off()
```

[image: bipartite_with asp]

This is looking better, but still not really what I want - see how some vertices are closer to each other than others?
So eventually I took the following approach. Setting the coordinates as bipartite looks like this

```
coords <- layout_as_bipartite(CCM_net)
coords
        [,1] [,2]
 [1,]  3.0    0
 [2,]  0.0    1
 [3,]  2.0    1
 [4,]  3.5    1
 [5,]  6.0    1
 [6,]  1.0    1
 [7,]  5.0    1
 [8,]  7.0    1
 [9,]  1.0    0
[10,]  4.5    0
[11,]  5.5    0
```

This matrix shows the x coordinates of your vertices in the first columns and the y coordinates in the second column, ordered according to your list with names. My list with names is

```
     id  name
1    EVI   EVI
2   MAXT  MAXT
3  MEANT MEANT
4   MINT  MINT
5      P     P
6    PET   PET
7     SM    SM
8     SR    SR
9    AMO   AMO
10   PDO   PDO
11   MEI   MEI
```

In my graph, EVI, AMO and PDO are on the bottom, but note their x coordinates: 3.0, 1.0, 4.5 and 5.5. I haven't figured out yet how the code comes up with that, but I don't like it so I simply changed it.

```
coords[,1]=c(2,0,4,8,12,16,20,24,9,16,24)
```

Now the plotting code (also with `asp`) and the output becomes

```
plot(CCM_net,
 layout=coords,
 edge.arrow.size=1,
 vertex.label.family="Helvetica",
 vertex.label.color="black",
 vertex.label.cex=1,
 vertex.label.dist=c(4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4),
 vertex.label.degree=c(pi/2,-pi/2,-pi/2,-pi/2,-pi/2,-pi/2,-pi/2,-pi/2,pi/2,pi/2,pi/2), #0 is right, “pi” is left, “pi/2” is below, and “-pi/2” is above
 edge.arrow.width=2,
 edge.lty=1,
 asp=0.6) # controls how rectangular the plot is. <1 = wide, >1 = tall
```

[image: bipartite_final]

Now the vertices are nicely spaced in a rectangular plot!

Note - I also decreased the size of the vertices, the size of the labels and their positioning, for better readability.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can output with PDF. then zoom in. 
Or, use `rgexf` package to output gexf file. Then visualizate in gephi.

I think gephi is a good tools for network visualization.